# Python 3 is skipping code.

Tags: python-3.x

im currently working on a project for school, but im having some trouble with it.

```
def index_district():

district = input("Please enter district: ")

candidates = []
var1 = 0
while var1:
    var1 += 1
    candidates_names = input('Enter name of candidate.  Hit enter again to end  ')
    if candidates_names == '':
        break
    candidates.append(candidates_names)

votes = []
var2 = 0
while var2:
    var2 += 1
    candidates_votes = input('Enter number of votes.  Hit enter again to end  ')
    if candidates_votes == '':
        break
    votes.append(candidates_votes)

parties = []
var3 = 0
while var3:
    var3 += 1
    candidates_parties = input('Enter party.  Hit enter again to end  ')
    if candidates_parties == '':
        break
    parties.append(candidates_parties)

canidate_parties = dict(zip(parties, candidates))

party_votes = dict(zip(parties, votes))

print(canidate_parties)
print(party_votes)
print(district)
#d1= canidate_parties, party_votes



index_district()
```

It gets the district, but then skips from district = input all the way to the print lines.

this is my output

```
Please enter district: dd
{}
{}
dd
```

I tried a smaller version of it with only 2 lists being made, and it worked perfectly.  So I'm a bit stumped at what I did wrong here.  any help would be appreciated.  thank you for your time.

Comment: The variables used in the while conditions start as false (because they are initialised to 0), therefore the loops never execute.

Comment: @Mark   it worked!  You're a beautiful man.  Any ideas on why it worked for the other one though if they were false?

Comment: None of the loops were executing. The reason `dd` is printed at the end is because it is successfully retrieved before any of the loops.